# @extend class animations cancel each other out

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a loading animation where the outer ring spins to the right, while the inner one spins to the left.

This is all the CSS code:

```
  html {
   height: 100%;
  }

  .loadingCircle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-top: solid 5px blue;
    border-radius: 50%;

    transform-origin: center center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.loadingCircleOuter {
  @extend .loadingCircle;

  animation: circleSpinOuter 2s linear infinite;
}

.loadingCircleInner {
  @extend .loadingCircle;

  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;

  animation: circleSpinInner 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes circleSpinOuter {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circleSpinInner {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}
```

Doing this results in the inner circle not spinning at all.
If I comment out the animation of the outer circle the inner one spins properly and making the inner circle spin twice as fast is enough to cancel the out the spin of the outer animation and add the proper spin to the left to it (oddly enough, only to it and not to the outer one, that one is still spinning correctly to the right).

It's clear that the outer animation is applied to both circles, but why?

I don't understand why it's behaving like that, changing the color of the outer circle does not apply the change to both circles, why does it alter the animation for both though?

Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too? At first sight it sounds like the answer is, of course the animation is applied to the children too; say moving a block of text around would look a bit silly if the <span>s and <em>s in the text would remain still in the original spot on the screen. So, that's logical. But then you say the colour of the inner circle doesn't change if you changed the colour of the outer one, which would mean the inner circle is not inside the outer one in the DOM. So can you post the HTML for clarification?

Comment: Whoops, you're correct. I'm new to scss and it's thee first time I had to use @extend. I was so surprised by that behavior that I thought it had to be css doing funny things ... turns out I had just nested the inner circle in the html. My bad.